# How can I merge strings of 0 or 1 as if I were doing an OR on bitfields in python?

Tags: python

For example, for the **strings** "000100", "010000", and "100000", I want the result to be "110100".

Is there a simple approach to this in Python?

Comment: Yes, there is. But first, what did you try to get this working?

Comment: Try looking for logical AND operation in python.

Comment: Hmm, not really guys! I think the operation you are looking for it bitwise OR.

Comment: @quamrana Ha, apparently I need to finish my coffee before doing any real thinking.

Comment: Yes, thinking is always good....

Comment: `res = 0b000100 | 0b010000 | 0b100000; print(f"{res:06b}")` ... see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=boolean#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types

Comment: Are those literal strings, ints in binary form? Please read about [ask] and provide a [mre]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert each binary string to their actual integer value by using `int(<str>, 2)`, then use the binary or operation (`|`) to merge them together and get the binary representation back by using `bin`:

```
>>> binstrings = ['000100', '010000', '100000']
>>> result = 0
>>> for s in binstrings:
...   result |= int(s, 2)
...
>>> result
52
>>> bin(result)
'0b110100'
```

Comment: Thanks! This was what I was looking for.

Comment: @Felap Please consider accepting this answer if it has solved your problem - It helps other people find the same solution without needing to ask the same question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to use a logical OR `|` operator.

```
a = 0b000100
b = 0b010000
c = 0b100000

merge = a | b | c
print(bin(merge))
```